# Is it possible to use a returned column value as a table name in an SQLite query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to write a query that examines all the tables in an SQLite database for a piece of information in order to simplify my post-incident diagnostics (performance doesn't matter).

I was hoping to write a query that uses [the sqlite_master table](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q7) to get a list of tables and then query them, all in one query:

```
SELECT Name 
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE Type = 'table' AND (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM Name
    WHERE conditions
    ) > 0;
```

However when attempting to execute this style of query, I receive an error `no such table: Name`.  Is there an alternate syntax that allows this, or is it simply not supported?

Comment: You can only do this using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is designed as an embedded database, i.e., to be used together with a 'real' programming language.
To be able to use such dynamic constructs, you must go outside of SQLite itself:

```py
cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    sql = "SELECT ... FROM {} WHERE ...".format(row[0])
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That code snippet was literally what I'd written up for use in the meantime.